# Api response not showing with curl in php

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to fetch Api response (created in nodejs) in website using Php,So for this i am using 
curl but its not working,I tried with following code but not working for me (showing blank page),Where i am wrong ? Here is my code

```
$post = ['email'=> "example@xyz.com",'password'=> "testing"];
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://35.154.149.228:8000/api/admin/login');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $result = json_decode($response); 
  print_R($result);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @ShubhamJain : output is blank, i am not getting anything,If i working in locahost then its working,if i running this in server then output showing blank page,you can check

Comment: This might be because your server is not able to connect to `http://35.154.149.228:8000/api/admin/login` ?

Comment: @ShubhamJain: Sir, what is the solution , what should i do ?

Comment: After trying your code without changing anything except including the php tags the response is:

stdClass Object
(
    [statusCode] => 401
    [error] => Unauthorized
    [message] => Invalid username or password
    [responseType] => INVALID_USER_PASS
)

Please let us know what your exact issue is, did you include the php open and close tags before and after your code?? <?php ?>

Comment: @Chuksy: : the response which you getting is fine but i am not getting same response like you,this is my problem

Comment: Did you post the actual IP and login credentials? You may want to edit them out if that's the case.

Comment: Check the new answer I posted, it involves forcing error reporting and printing the raw response from the server before decoding it.

Answer (score 0):

change your post array

```
  $post = array('email'=> "example@xyz.com",'password'=> "testing");
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://35.154.149.228:8000/api/admin/login');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $result = json_decode($response); 
  print_r($result);
```

Comment: Why should OP do that?

Comment: print_R($result) please change to print_r($result)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$result = json_decode($response);
```

To

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);
```

Then

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Response:-

```
Array
(
 [statusCode] => 401
 [error] => Unauthorized
 [message] => Invalid username or password
 [responseType] => INVALID_USER_PASS
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying errors just in case the errors/warnings are suppressed.

use these at the top of the file, just after the php tags

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also try to print the raw response before json_decoding it, this is because if the response you are getting is not valid json nothing would be printed out after decoding it.

Use this

```
print_r("The response is: " . $response);
```

In summarry your code should look like

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$post = ['email'=> "example@xyz.com",'password'=> "testing"];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://35.154.149.228:8000/api/admin/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Printing the original response before trying to decode it
//$result = json_decode($response); 

print_r("The response from the server before decoding is: " . $response);
```

Let us know what the exact response you get from this is